# How to fix pSX error Incorrect Header

Tags: emulation, ps1

I have [pSX v1.13](http://psxemulator.gazaxian.com/) running on my computer, but when I downloaded CTR: Crash Team Racing from [doperoms.com](http://www.doperoms.com/), the emulator comes back with the following error on the console:

```
iso9660: incorrect header
```

Anyone know a means of fixing this?

Comment: Chances are good it's a corrupt ISO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the file is corrupt which means it just won't work.